# Stuck on an exercise regarding orthonormal bases.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products, orthonormal, change-of-basis

Given a basis $e_1, e_2, e_3$ for $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $||e_1||=1$, $||e_1||=\sqrt{2}$, $||e_1||=\sqrt{3}$ and

$e_1\cdot  e_2 = 1$, $e_1\cdot  e_3 = 1$, $e_2\cdot  e_3 = 1$

I'm asked to find an orthonormal basis $B$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ in terms of $e_1, e_2, e_3$. I try to use Gram-Schimdt but get stuck.

---

**My attempt:**

Let $v_2=e_2-\text{proj}_{e_1}e_2=e_2-(e_1\cdot e_2)e_1=e_2-e_1$.
Since the length of the projection is $1$, and the length of $e_2$ is $\sqrt{2}$, we have that $||e_2-e_1||=1$. Now let

$$v_3=e_3-\text{proj}_{e_1,e_2}e_3=e_3-(e_3e_1)e_1-(e_3e_2)e_2=e_3-e_1-2e_2$$

the length of $\text{proj}_{e_1,e_2}e_3$ is $$\sqrt{||\text{proj}_{e_1}e_3||^2+||\text{proj}_{e_2}e_3||^2}=\sqrt{(e_3e_1)^2e_1+(e_3e_2)^2e_2}=\sqrt{1+4}=\sqrt{5}$$

yet this certainly can't be since $||e_3||=\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: I suppose that you meant to write that $||e_1||=1$, $||e_{\color{red}2}||=\sqrt{2}$, and $||e_{\color{red}3}||=\sqrt{3}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $f_1=e_1$. Now, let\begin{align}a_2&=e_2-(e_2.f_1)f_1\\&=e_2-e_1\end{align}and let\begin{align}f_2&=\frac{a_2}{\|a_2\|}\\&=\frac{e_2-e_1}{\|e_2-e_1\|}\\&=e_2-e_1.\end{align}Finally, let\begin{align}a_3&=e_3-(e_3.f_1)f_1-(e_3.f_2)f_2\\&=e_3-(e_3.e_1)e_1-\bigl(e_3.(e_2-e_1)\bigr)(e_2-e_1)\\&=e_3-e_1\end{align}and let\begin{align}f_3&=\frac{a_3}{\|a_3\|}\\&=\frac{e_3-e_1}{\|e_3-e_1\|}\\&=\frac{e_3-e_1}{\sqrt2}.\end{align}Then $B=\{f_1,f_2,f_3\}$.

Comment: Well, silly me.

Comment: Actually, where does the last $\sqrt{2}$ come from? Wouldn't it still be true that $||\text{proj}_{e_1,f_2}e_3||=\sqrt{||\text{proj}_{e_1}e_3||^2+||\text{proj}_{f_2}e_3||^2}=\sqrt{1+1}=\sqrt{2}$? Thus $||a_3||^2=||e_3||^2-||\text{proj}_{e_1,f_2}e_3||^2$ and $||a_3||=1$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Since$$\|e_1-e_3\|^2=\|e_1\|^2+\|e_3\|^2-2(e_1.e_3)=1+3-2=2,$$we have $\|e_1-e_3\|=\sqrt2$.

Comment: Ah I see. Do you happen by chance to see what is wrong about my reasoning though?

Comment: Since $e_3$ and $f_2(=e_1-e_2)$ are orthogonal, $\operatorname{proj}_{f_2}e_3=0$.

Comment: Why do you think these are orthogonal? Wouldn't $e_3(e_2-e_1)=e_3e_2-e_3e_1=2-1=1?$

Comment: No: $e_3.(e_2-e_1)=e_3.e_2-e_3.e_1=1-1=0$.